# How Can I make & send array of dictionary (JSON Format ) send to server using Alamofire in swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, alamofire

I have tried to create & send array of dictionary JSON format to Alamofire.

```
 {
"attendance": [{
    "attndid":"0",
    "psngrtype": "student",
    "date":currentdate,
    "cuid": "25",
    "enttid": "21",

}] }
```

Here, I am used tableview, In the above "cuid" & "enttid" I giving value from selectable tableview cell data. remaining are constant. I am passing one array of dictionary, if i select one tableview cell data. and two array, if i select two cells.etc.. 
and I am using below code and I get but getting issue create dictionary format.
My code:

```
 let arrayOfDictionaries: [[String:AnyObject]] =
        [
        ["psngrtype":"student" as AnyObject,
         "attndid": "0" as AnyObject ,
         "cuid":stdpasngerid as AnyObject,
         "enttid": entitID as AnyObject,
         "attnddate":CurrentDate as AnyObject ]]

          print(arrayOfDictionaries.toJSONString())

extension Collection where Iterator.Element == [String:AnyObject] {
func toJSONString(options: JSONSerialization.WritingOptions = .prettyPrinted) -> String {
    if let arr = self as? [[String:AnyObject]],
        let dat = try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: arr, options: options),
        let str = String(data: dat, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8) {
        return str
    }
    return "[]"
} }
```

output:

```
[{
"enttid" : "1",
"psngrtype" : "student",
"attnddate" : "10-26-2017",
"attndid" : "0",
"cuid" : "25" }]
```

And I want to add first one like json format.and add multiple array if i select more than one tableview cell. Please help i am stuck?

Comment: Not related, but servers don't care about pretty printed JSON at all.

Comment: @vadian Thanks!  So, Can you please let me know some examples. If don't mine.

Comment: I just mean to change the default writing options to `[]`

Comment: @vadian Yes, i did it. But server did not accept my format. Its accept that above format. That's my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Simply you can do

```
var finalArray:[String:String] = [:]
finalArray["Attandance"] = arrayOfDictionaries.toJSONString()
```

Comment: Yes, I tried with this one but problem with removing \n..  ' print(finalArray) ' output:   ' ["attendance": "[\n  {\n    \"enttid\" : \"1\",\n    \"status\" : \"\",\n    \"clsid\" : \"45\",\n    \"psngrtype\" : \"student\",\n    \"attnddate\" : \"10-26-2017\",\n    \"isactive\" : \"true\",\n    \"psngrid\" : \"\",\n    \"attndid\" : \"0\",\n    \"cuid\" : \"25\"\n  }\n]"]
'   problem with removing \n from [string:string] . I stuck with it.  Thanks

Comment: To remove \n from your string you can use:  `let dictString = String(yourJsonString.characters.filter { !”\n”.characters.contains($0) })`

Answer (score 0):

> Object Mapping, you can use ObjectMapper library.

Create object Attendance like

```
class Attendance: Mappble {
 var objects: [AttendancesAttributes] = []
 init () { }
 required init?(map:Map) { }

 func mapping(map: Map){
   objects <- map["attendance"]
 }
}
```

Then creates your AttendancesAttributes object

```
class AttendancesAttributes: Mappable {
    var id: String
    ....
   func mapping(map: Map) {
      //do the mapping with your dictionary
   }
}
```

Then in your VC I guess you can do

```
var attendance: Attendance = Attendance()
func (_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
     //check if your object is or not in your array.
   attendance.objects.append(yourTableViewFeeder[indexPath.row])
}
```

and finally in your API Client:

```
 func sendAttendanceInformationsToServer(attendance: Attendance) {
   Alamofire.request(url, method, parameters: attendance.toJSON(), encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: ["":""]).responseJSON (completionHandler: { //deal your response here
  })
 }
```

Comment: I installed pod of object Mapper. Next Its showing error is Use of Undeclared type Mappble, when I was creating object class.  code:  ' class Attendance: Mappble {
 var objects: [AttendancesAttributes] = []
 init () { }
 required init?(map:Map) { }

 func mapping(map: Map){
   objects <- map["attendance"]
 }
} '

Comment: Import Object Mapper in your files.

Comment: can you please let me know some example of this method '  class AttendancesAttributes: Mappable {
        var id: String = ""
        
        func mapping(map: Map) {
            //do the mapping with your dictionary
        }
    }
' Error:  It's showing does not confirm protocol. And I am using UISwitch into tableview cell , switch is ON (default). when user switch OFF i am getting ID of the row data. How can I add to here.  Please help i am stuck.

Comment: In the AttendanceAttributes add all the variables you need.

Then implement the protocol : func mapping(map: Map) AND required init?(map: Map) (you miss the initializer).

Can you show me the code of the UITableView/UITableViewCell? I'll be happy to help you with that.

Comment: '  class Attendance: Mappable {
        var objects: [AttendancesAttributes] = []
        init () { }
        required init?(map:Map) { }
        
        func mapping(map: Map){
            objects <- map["attendance"]
        }
    }
    class AttendancesAttributes: Mappable {
        var id: String = ""
        
        func mapping(map: Map) {
            //do the mapping with your dictionary
        }
    }
'   classAttendanceAttributs:Mappable showing error still   error is: Type ClassAtendance.AttendancesAttributs does not conform to protocol 'Mappable'

Comment: Add required init?(map: Map) { } in the class AttendancesAttributes.

Comment: Thanks for the response ! it's fine. My Tableview cellforrowatindex:  '
        cell.present.isOn = true
        cell.present.tag = indexPath.row
        cell.present.addTarget(self, action:#selector(self.SwitchToggle) , for: .valueChanged)' .    And switch Action Method:   ' func SwitchToggle(sender: AnyObject) {       
 let id  = ((attendanceArray[sender.tag]) as AnyObject).value(forKey: "psngrid") as? String
        if  active == 1
        {
            studentIsON = "a"
            stdpasngerid = id!
        }
    }' Now, How Can i adding array  depend on selected switches ?

Comment: can you please give me your email ID. I'll share my code. if don't mine. Thanks

Comment: alexandre.odet@epitech.eu

Comment: Thank you ! I have sent my files. Can you please check once. Thanks Again.