# CarbonKit : How To pass tab array title ID to UIViewController?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, carbonkit

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7L2AZ.png)I'm using `CarbonKit` in `ViewController`. Its working fine. Here, I'm using one `tableview` for all Segment Array title ID. And i got title ID when i was selected Tab and swipe, and stuck with passing array title ID to server(`TableView`) when i'll changing index from left ---> right & right ---> left.

My Code: Names Array

```
 self.carbonTabSwipeNavigation = CarbonTabSwipeNavigation(items: self.names as [AnyObject], delegate: self)
```

setting `ViewController`

```
 func carbonTabSwipeNavigation(_ carbonTabSwipeNavigation: CarbonTabSwipeNavigation, viewControllerAt index: UInt) -> UIViewController {

    studentid = studentidArray.object(at: Int(index)) as! String
    print(studentid)
    return self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeaveTableVC") as! LeaveTableVC
}
```

I has shown names on 'ViewController' with 'tableview'. Now I need to send name of ID to server, when swipe and tap the segment tab.  Please help i'm stuck. Thank you

Comment: Do you need to pass the title of its tab to your current view controller ?

Comment: @FrancescoDeliro  Yes, I gave array list to tab (this array list coming from server). Its working fine. Here, Each of array having ID (Array). I want pass ID to server, when i move to current and next tableview. I'm using One Tableview for all segment tab. just data will be changing depend on array ID.

Comment: So LeaveTableVC is where you load your server data and it’s the same controller for all your tabs. I think that in this view controller you have your logic for your server query, is it correct? And studentID is the parameter you want to send to the server?

Comment: @FrancescoDeliro. Once check my update Post. I created separate 'viewcontroller' and add into 'carbonkit viewcontroller'. Yes, studentID is the parameter and send to server. right

Comment: Ok thank you, I have edited my answer ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok if I understand the thing is that your LeaveTableVC is the root view controller of the Carbon Kit controller, I think that would be better if you use a different TableViewController that could be the same for all your tabs, but anyway studentID is not your new LeaveTableVC instance property but is the current LeaveTableVC property. So for example you need to do:

```
func carbonTabSwipeNavigation(_ carbonTabSwipeNavigation: CarbonTabSwipeNavigation, viewControllerAt index: UInt) -> UIViewController {
    let nextVC = self.storyboard!.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "LeaveTableVC") as! LeaveTableVC
    nextVC.studentid = studentidArray.object(at: Int(index)) as! String
    print(studentid)
    return nextVC
}
```

Comment: Thanks ! It's my fault. I did mistake  'return self' instead of as u like. Thank you Again.

Comment: Can you please check this one : [link] (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46949490/how-can-i-make-send-array-of-dictionary-json-format-send-to-server-using-al)

Comment: Sure, I will check it ;) and you can accept my answer here, thanks!